# How To Use Force Fields In Geometry/Simulation Nodes? [W/ .Blend]

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I apologize if this is obvious, but I'm still learning Geometry nodes and I'm stuck. I built this node tree from a video on YouTube, and what I have it doing is behaving like snow particles blowing away from a mound of snow. I figured out how to integrate gravity into the particle simulation, but I'm stuck trying to find a way to use a wind force field object to blow the particles off to the side. I know I can use the vector node that is making the gravity, but I want it to be more dynamic and easily controlled than that. Thanks for the continued help and support!

[image: My Geometry Nodes]

[image: Closer Look At The Simulation Nodes Portion]

[image]

Comment: You can edit your question, you don't have to delete it and ask again. Your first screenshot is still illegible. And as I said the last time - wind is just a force like gravity is. You say you figured out how to integrate gravity.  Now do the same again but with values for X and Y instead of Z. I cannot give you example values because I don't know how much you want the wind to blow in which direction (hint: the axis in which direction you want the wind to blow is where you have to add or subtract something).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Hey Gordon, thanks for helping me again. I deleted my old post and reposted because it was downvoted and buried now. I just wasn't sure if providing the blend would help any. I did make a cheat way to use the wind force object, but it only used the location to determine the direction the particles move. If there's no real way to integrate it, I'll just use my Vector values.

Comment: The method of closing and opening duplicate questions will only lead to more downvotes in the future when people perhaps already commented and get annoyed to have to do it again and again... Anyway, Geometry Nodes is not a physics engine, that's why you cannot integrate existing force fields and for the same reason you have to create a gravitational force by yourself as well.

Comment: ...of course when I say you cannot integrate them I mean as a physical force. You can still use them with an _Object Info_ node to get their location, rotation etc.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Gotcha, so I already reached the extent of what I can do. I assumed since Simulation Nodes exist now, it would incorporate like, the things that get used for simulations, but I imagine that's in the pipeline down the road somewhere.

Comment: Well, but the name _Simulation Nodes_ does not mean it incorporates simulations outside of _Geometry Nodes_. Just like a _Rigid Body_ simulation is not affected by a _Fluid_ simulation as another example. The different physics engines do not (or only to some extent) work together. And the _Simulation Zone_ is not even a physics engine. You only "simulate" movements in geometry by mathematical operations that you can (or rather have to) define manually by yourself.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ohhh, I see. I was wondering why I had to use Vector Math to mimic physics, I thought I was missing something. So what is the extent of Simulation Nodes? I thought they were meant to replace the Physics tab, but it's more an addition to what Geometry Nodes do?

Comment: The _Simulation Zone_ allows to have the result of one frame influence the next frame (similar to a physics simulation), what was not possible without it. Before, calculations could be based on the frame number but were independent from previous frames. I hope you get an idea now. The comments section is not intended for long discussions or chatting.